# RS232 library for .net core

Tags: serial-port, nuget, visual-studio-code, .net-core, ports

We are developing applications in .Net Core and one of them require to access a serial port.

As I learned that System.IO.Ports won't be implemented in .Net Core, I was looking for a nuget library that supplies that functionality, but couldn't get one compatible with .net core (VS Code is showing an error message).

Is there any alternative out there?

**UPDATE**: I found that the official SerialPort API is being taken into consideration for porting to .Net Core (see https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/984)

Comment: Ive been looking for this also, not had much luck yet.

Comment: Looking here as well.

Comment: Me too :( .....

Comment: Anyone had luck ?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989538/serial-communication-with-silverlight-5-com-port

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is now fully cross platform in 2021.

Simply NuGet install either using the command line or your IDE : "System.IO.Ports"

The following example is a .NET 5 console mode program that compiles and works on both Linux and Windows.

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace PipelinesTest
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Reading a GPS Device on COM3");

      SerialPort _port = new SerialPort("COM3", 4800, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

      _port.DataReceived += PortOnDataReceived;
      _port.Open();
      
      Console.WriteLine("Press Return to Exit");
      Console.ReadLine();

      _port.Close();
      _port.DataReceived -= PortOnDataReceived;
      
      Console.WriteLine("Ended");
    }

    private static void PortOnDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
      SerialPort port = sender as SerialPort;
      var line = port.ReadLine();
      Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
  }
}
```

NOTE: I should have mentioned when I first answered this, you'll need to change the "COM3" in the constructor above to something like "/dev/ttys0" or similar for Linux.  You *MIGHT* also have to run your app as Root/SU on a Linux machine, this is just the nature of Linux's multi user security unfortunately.

Answer (score 8):

I managed to compile https://github.com/jcurl/SerialPortStream for netstandard1.5 with some minor modifications.

Have a look at the pull request: https://github.com/jcurl/SerialPortStream/pull/13

Experimental nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/SerialPortStreamCore/2.1.0

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try and see what happens

Comment: FYI: I just got a basic serial app up and running on Windows 10 and Raspbian, using the SerialPortStream 2.1.2 library. I built the simple app using dotnet 2.0 and Visual Studio Code. Seems to work well!