# Using System.IO.Ports.SerialPort in .NET Core 1.1

Tags: c#, serial-port, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I'm trying to create an console application using visual studio code with .Net Core and get all available ports. How to use `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` [class](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.IO.Ports) in visual studio code?
I try to declare it with `using` statement but the only available is `Compression` and `MemoryMappedFiles` in namespace `System.IO`.

I'm using .Net Core 1.1.1 SDK

Comment: It is the usual issue with .NETCore, it isn't done yet.  Code skeleton was checked-in a [month ago](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.IO.Ports/src/System/IO/Ports), it is targeted for the [2.0 release](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/15671).  Ought to be a while, no sign yet of any attempt to port this to Unix.

Comment: Thanks, I see. will wait for official release to use it.

Answer (score 7):

For those coming to this post some years later...

Since .NET Core 2.0 it's possible to use the [`System.IO.Ports` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Ports/).

Answer (score 6):

If you are using linux OS you can use [SerialPortStream](https://github.com/jcurl/SerialPortStream) library. It requires the libserial binaries and I was able to compile it only for linux (not for MacOS or Windows).

Other way is using the Mono implementation and [Mono.Posix.NETStandard](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.Posix.NETStandard/1.0.0-beta2) package. This way works only for NETStandard 2.0 projects.

I copied sources of System.IO.Ports classes from Mono into my NETStandard 2.0 project, added the Mono.Posix.NETStandard, Microsoft.Win32.Registry references and included `<AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>` section into my .csproj file. And it works on MacOs and Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Please use the .NET API Browser.
SerialPort not present for .NET Core 1.1:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?term=serialport&view=netcore-1.1
but it was added in .NET Core 2.0:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?term=serialport&view=netcore-2.0
You can always add reference to System.IO.dll from main Framework to get the SerialPort, but then You are not .NET Core 1.1 conform (cannot port to Linux, MacOS etc)

Comment: .net core 2.0 is on linux

Answer (score -6):

System.IO.Ports will present in the system.dll so by default it will be added to your project when you create it.

then you need to add

```
Using System.IO.Ports Namespace to your class
```

This is sample which will give us the Available ports.

```
private void getAllAvailablePorts()
 {
     // Get a list of serial port names.
     string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

     Console.WriteLine("The following serial ports were found:");

     // Display each port name to the console.
     foreach (string port in ports)
     {
       Console.WriteLine(port);
      }
}
```

Comment: I can't import System.IO.Ports in .Net Core using visual studio code

Comment: sry i think this link can help you out.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40689840/rs232-library-for-net-core

Comment: it seems it is not ready as @Hans Passant said in comment above.