# .NET core 3.0 System.IO.Ports SerialPort uses 5-10% CPU on RPI all the time

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, raspberry-pi, serial-port

When I try to read from a serial port (uart) in Linux on an RaspberryPi I always get a CPU load of 5-10% when in a loop. As SerialPorts should be blocking, this shouldn't use that much cpu load, or am I wrong?

I tried two codes:

#### Simple Code

```
var port = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyUSB0", 57600);
port.Open();
while (true)
{
    if (port.BytesToRead > 0)
    {
    while (port.BytesToRead > 0)
        Console.Write($"{port.ReadByte().ToString("X2")} ");
    Console.WriteLine("");
    }
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

#### Advanced Code

```
static int blockLimit = 100;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var port = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyUSB0", 57600);
    port.Open();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[blockLimit];
    Action kickoffRead = null;
    kickoffRead = delegate
    {
        port.BaseStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, delegate (IAsyncResult ar)
        {
        try
        {
            int actualLength = port.BaseStream.EndRead(ar);
            byte[] received = new byte[actualLength];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, received, 0, actualLength);
            raiseAppSerialDataEvent(received);
        }
        catch (IOException exc)
        {
            handleAppSerialError(exc);
        }
        kickoffRead();
        }, null);
    };
    kickoffRead();

    while (true)
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

private static void handleAppSerialError(IOException exc)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private static void raiseAppSerialDataEvent(byte[] received)
{
    Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(received));
}
```

Both with the same result: Two processes which uses together 5% to 10% cpu load
[image: htop cpu%]

Using `.NET Core 3.0 Preview 2` and `System.IO.Ports 4.6.0-preview-19073.11` on a `RaspberryPi 3b+` running with `HypriotOS 1.10.0`

Comment: I have the same problem. After migration from Mono to Net Core my cpu usage went from 5% to 25%

Problem is that SerialStream implementation in NET Core uses async operations everywhere, even for synchronous Read/Write operations.

see
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.IO.Ports/src/System/IO/Ports/SerialStream.Unix.cs

Using async/await operations comes at the price. Thread context switching or creating SerialStreamIORequest objects isn't free.

Solution is to use mono or try to use some other implementation.

Comment: What library are you referencing? Where is the `SerialPort` class that you are referencing? I will like to have something similar

Answer (score 3):

As for now (NET Core 3.1) SerialPort implementation is very CPU intensive. I've ported Mono SerialPort to Net Standard library according to dima117 response here
[.NET Core - Use System.IO.Ports.SerialPort in visual studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42711396/net-core-use-system-io-ports-serialport-in-visual-studio-code)

I've published it to github:

https://github.com/michaldobrodenka/System.IO.Ports.Mono

With this SerialPort implementation, CPU usage dropped from 25% to 5% on my allwinner h3 hw

Comment: It's on NuGet.org https://www.nuget.org/packages/SystemIOPorts.SerialPort_Mono/

Comment: Here is latest version which is not dependent on MonoPosixHelper - calling libc directly https://github.com/michaldobrodenka/Mono.IO.Ports-managed

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem and did some profiling using Jetbrains's dotTrace. I got the following info:

```
7.71%   Poll  •  25,862/25,862 ms  •  Interop+Serial.Poll(SafeHandle, PollEvents, Int32, out PollEvents)
  7.71%   PollEvents  •  System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.PollEvents(Int32, Boolean, Boolean, out Nullable)
    7.71%   IOLoop  •  System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.IOLoop
      7.71%   InnerInvoke  •  System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke
         Thread #8
```

7 procent was about the same as I saw when running `top -d 1`.

Looking at the called methods I assume that polling is used, which is not very efficient. Especially if the polling interval is very short. So i took a look at the dotnet source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.IO.Ports/src/System/IO/Ports/SerialStream.Unix.cs#L845) and noticed that the interval is hard-coded to 1 ms (line 845).

```
Interop.PollEvents events = PollEvents(
    1,
    pollReadEvents: hasPendingReads,
    pollWriteEvents: hasPendingWrites,
    out Interop.ErrorInfo? error);
```

I'll see if I can create an issue at the GitHub repo.

Comment: There already is an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/2379), and it seems to be a big problem to solve